# Adding someone else's code into the question

Tags: discussion, editing, vote-to-close, third-party

Code behind a link is off-topic. Good.

Questions trying it anyway get closed. Good.

But every once in a while I encounter a question which is quite good and where this is the only problem. Now, I don't want to spoil every brand new person arriving here with a free service (oh, wait...), but if I copy the code from behind the link into the question there no longer is a problem.

1. Are these considered *legal* edits?
2. Are such edits discouraged?